# whats mens heap size in micro stm32f10x start up?

Tags: arm, microcontroller

i use keil for stm32f10x,in start up there is some words.
whats menas Heap_Size Heapbase in startup micro stm32f10x??

a part of start up files

```
Heap_Size EQU 0x00000200

AREA HEAP, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
__heap_base
Heap_Mem SPACE Heap_Size
__heap_limit

PRESERVE8
THUMB
```

can any guide me?

Comment: http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Answer (score 1):

Heap is a region of memory to be used for memory allocation, when malloc() or calloc() is used. If memory allocation will not be used by the application, then it is not important. My compiler stores by default 10 bytes for the heap, and I leave it like this. If memory allocation will be used, then you must make sure that the heap size will be larger compared to the size you will allocate from the software. I don't use Keil, but I'm pretty sure that "base" is the start address of the heap inside RAM and "size" is how may bytes the heap will be. If you don't know what to do, then edit the size from Keil settings and let the linker decide on base address.